# Get the value for a id with the latest date at least 6 months ago in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies for the vague question, please help me make this question more clear apart from answering it.

Below is the pandas.DataFrame that I have "df" and the pandas.DataFrame that I would like "df1".

"df1" has a column "val_6_months_ago" that shows the "val" of an "id" 6 months ago.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 
                   'val': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                   'date': [datetime(2019,4,1), datetime(2019,12,1), datetime(2020,1,1), datetime(2018,1,1), datetime(2020,1,1)]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 
                    'val':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                    'date':[datetime(2019,4,1), datetime(2019,12,1), datetime(2020,1,1), datetime(2018,1,1), datetime(2020,1,1)],
                    'val_6_months_ago':[None, 1, 1, None, 4]})
```

Comment: 6 months ago from today or from the max date for that specific ID ?

Comment: @Datanovice 6 months ago from that row's date column value

Comment: It's still not very clear, for example there are 8 & 9 months distance from the first date of id `a` is that your measuring stick ? or are you doing a cumulative measure of distance, of `2019-04-01` from `2019-12-01` and then `2019-12-01` from `2020-01-01`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a 'self-join' with `pd.merge_asof` and calculate date using `pd.DateOffset`:

```
df['date_6_months_ago'] = df['date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=6)

df_out = pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values('date_6_months_ago'), df[['id','date','val']].sort_values('date'), 
                       left_on='date_6_months_ago', 
                       right_on='date', 
                       by='id',
                       direction='backward', 
                       suffixes=('','_6_months_ago'))\
           .drop('date_6_months_ago', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  id  val       date  val_6_months_ago
1  a    1 2019-04-01               NaN
2  a    2 2019-12-01               1.0
3  a    3 2020-01-01               1.0
0  b    4 2018-01-01               NaN
4  b    5 2020-01-01               4.0
```

Comment: Clever answer @ScottBoston.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Thank you.

Comment: @ScottBoston the solution works like a charm on the data in the question. Thanks. However, when I try it on my actual data I get this error: "TypeError: Function call with ambiguous argument types". Any suggestions?

Comment: Hrm.. that error doesn't see like a pandas error.  Can you create data that will duplicate this problem?  Maybe append the full stacktrace of this error to the bottom of this question.

Comment: Sorry, it was just that my date columns were of the object type. I changed them to datetime and it works just fine now. Thanks a lot!